# Read SQL table into SparklyR

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, sparklyr

How can one connect a SQL table to R using SparklyR? The [cheatsheet](http://spark.rstudio.com/images/sparklyr-cheatsheet.pdf) shows that you can use `DBI::dbWriteTable`, but does not mention `DBI::dbReadTable`. Let's say that my table is here:

```
driver = "SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
server = "corsql10.corwin.local"
database = "Project_DB"
table = "Participants"
```

Responses with example code are preferred. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dan,

You can try something like this:

```
install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github('imanuelcostigan/RSQLServer')
require(RSQLServer)
require(dplyr)

src <- RSQLServer::src_sqlserver("corsql10.corwin.local", database = "Project_DB")
data <- tbl(src, "Participants")

DBI::dbWriteTable(sc, "spark_Participants", data)
```

First, define the data source from SQL Server. Second, write it to Spark. `tbl` should create a reference to the SQL Server table without loading it into memory.  It looks like the RSQLServer package is not well maintained and CRAN took it down because the author didn't fix its bugs... So you will have to trouble shoot it. Here is a good resource: [Accessing MSSQL Server with R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/accessing-mssql-server-with-r-rsqlserver-with-dplyr/)

Comment: This is excellent, but I'm not able to test because `odbc` does not install on my R version. Can you suggest a different driver? I've tried `SQLite`, but could not figure out the rest of this `dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), )`. Vignette says "SQLite only needs a path to the database."

Comment: Can you use RODBC?

Comment: I'll update the answer's code if that package works for you

Comment: RODBC would be perfect, I've already experimented with that but was not able to get it going

Comment: `Error in UseMethod("tbl") : 
      no applicable method for 'tbl' applied to an object of class "RODBC"`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get `RSQLServer` installed either due to my company's R version (issue with `bindrcpp` dependancy).

Comment: I'd say you've got to work with IT to update R and then use odbc/RSQLServer with the correct drivers installed... Good luck!